# Change Jenkins Status color or provide a message

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I want to write a script for Jenkins which will change the status color of the jenkins from blue to green once the job is successful.

I am not much aware of the shell scripting, Can someone guide me on how and where should I start from?

Or is there any way I can provide a message as I have attached the screenshot..
The message for testing can be anything like "pipeline is passed"

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This plugin may be one of solutions: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/badge/
A lot of options to add badges, text to Build History

[image: Example of result]

Pipeline script for this specific result in scripted pipeline

```
node('master') {
    stage('test') {
        addShortText('pipeline has passed')
    }
}
```

Note: Same results can be achieved in declarative pipeline for code generation go to [yourJenkinsAddress/pipeline-syntax/](http://yourJenkinsAddress/pipeline-syntax/) and select addShortText, addBadge or any other method from this plugin in Sample Step:

[Pipeline-syntax generation example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/psdkF.png)

Comment: Yes this is what exactly is required @RaspberryCode . 
But I am new and unable to achieve it. Little confused on where to start from. Can you please provide me some basic steps to achieve that ?

Comment: Can you show me the pipeline line which you added? 
Also, is it possible to run any curl command and update it?
Like if we want to provide any curl command and add a line "pipeline is successful" manually? is it possible?

Comment: I have added code example. As for your second questions: I would highly recommend avoiding such hacks as rewriting Jenkins job history using curl. Jenkins as a code has great amount of flexibility on its own.
If you want to have 'manual' control at job status see [Steve Miskiewicz answer for similar question](https://superuser.com/a/1179902)  - but that is different question whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

The default color for successful job is blue (Meant pipeline is successful). I don't think you can add another message or color. You can try customize the the build name with the [Build Name Setter](https://plugins.jenkins.io/build-name-setter/).

Jenkins also have another status - [unstable](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/glossary/#build-status) which means non-failed errors.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To change color from blue to green just install green balls plugin))